# Why assinging an observable with a mapped object works with input, but not with select?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, mapping

Consider the following two examples of mapping an object from JSON and assigning it into an observable:

The first example enables the user to change the input value, save the current value, and load the saved data anytime:

```js
var personAsJson = "";
var handlerVM = function () {
  var self = this;
  self.person = ko.observable();
  self.init = function () {
    self.person(new personVM("john", 1));
  }
  self.changeName = function () {
    var currentName = "";
    var vowels = "aieou";
    var consonants = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz";
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      currentName += vowels.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * vowels.length));
      currentName += consonants.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * consonants.length));
    }
    self.person().name(currentName);
  }
  self.save = function () {
    personAsJson = ko.toJSON(self.person);
    console.log(personAsJson);
  }
  self.load = function () {
    loadedPerson = ko.mapping.fromJSON(personAsJson);
    self.person(loadedPerson);
  }
  self.log = function () {
    console.log(ko.toJSON(self.person));
  }
}
var personVM = function (name, id) {
  var self = this;
  self.name = ko.observable(name);
  self.id = ko.observable(id);
}

var handler = new handlerVM();
handler.init();
ko.applyBindings(handler);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/SteveSanderson/knockout.mapping/master/build/output/knockout.mapping-latest.js
"></script>
<div data-bind="with: person">
  <input data-bind="value: name" />
</div>
<div>
  <button data-bind="text: 'change name', click: changeName" />
  <button data-bind="text: 'save', click: save" />
  <button data-bind="text: 'load', click: load" />
  <button data-bind="text: 'log current person', click: log" />
</div>
```

The second example does the same thing - only with a select. However, the load functionality doesn't work:

```js
var currentPersonAsJson = "";
var handlerVM = function () {
  var self = this;
  self.persons = ko.observableArray([
      new personVM("john", 1),
      new personVM("paul", 2),
      new personVM("viki", 3),  
  ]); 
  self.currentPerson = ko.observable();     
  self.save = function () {
    currentPersonAsJson = ko.toJSON(self.currentPerson);
    console.log(currentPersonAsJson);
  }
  self.load = function () {
    loadedPerson = ko.mapping.fromJSON(currentPersonAsJson);
    self.currentPerson(loadedPerson);
  }
  self.log = function () {
    console.log(ko.toJSON(self.currentPerson));
  }
}
var personVM = function (name, id) {
  var self = this;
  self.name = ko.observable(name);
  self.id = ko.observable(id);
}

var handler = new handlerVM();
ko.applyBindings(handler);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/SteveSanderson/knockout.mapping/master/build/output/knockout.mapping-latest.js
"></script>
<div>
  <div>
     <select data-bind="options: persons,
                        optionsText: 'name',
                        optionsCaption: 'choose a person',
                        value: currentPerson"
     >
     </select>
  </div>
  <div>
     <button data-bind="text: 'save', click: save" />
     <button data-bind="text: 'load', click: load" />
     <button data-bind="text: 'log current person', click: log" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Why the second example doesn't work, and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you change the `<select>`'s value through code, knockout searches for the new value in the list of `options` so it can update the UI.

When you set `currentPerson` (which is bound to the `value`) to anything that is **not** present in the `persons` array (which is bound to `options`), the UI will not update.

When you're saving a person, you're serializing to JSON. After reconstructing, you receive a new object that knockout cannot match with the previously bound options.

There are two possible solutions:

1. Use the `optionsValue` binding so knockout uses the `id` property to match persons rather than an instance check, or
2. Do a manual search for a previously created viewmodel when loading a person.

I've implemented solution 2 in the example below.

```js
var currentPersonAsJson = null;

var handlerVM = function () {
  var self = this;
  self.persons = ko.observableArray([
      new PersonVM("john", 1),
      new PersonVM("paul", 2),
      new PersonVM("viki", 3),  
  ]); 
  self.currentPerson = ko.observable();     
  self.save = function () {
    currentPersonAsJson = ko.toJSON(self.currentPerson);
    console.log(currentPersonAsJson);
  }
  self.load = function () {
    var loadedPerson = ko.mapping.fromJSON(currentPersonAsJson);
    // loadedPerson is a new instance, so it won't match anything
    // inside self.persons
    // Let's do a manual lookup:
    
    var matchedVM = self.persons().find(
      p => p.id() === loadedPerson.id
    );
    
    if (matchedVM) {
      loadedPerson = matchedVM;
    }
    // Edge case: We've loaded something that we don't know:
    else {
      self.persons.push(loadedPerson);
    }
    
    self.currentPerson(loadedPerson);
  }
  self.log = function () {
    console.log(ko.toJSON(self.currentPerson));
  }
}
var PersonVM = function (name, id) {
  var self = this;
  self.name = ko.observable(name);
  self.id = ko.observable(id);
}

var handler = new handlerVM();
ko.applyBindings(handler);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/SteveSanderson/knockout.mapping/master/build/output/knockout.mapping-latest.js
"></script>
<div>
  <div>
     <select data-bind="options: persons,
                        optionsText: 'name',
                        optionsCaption: 'choose a person',
                        value: currentPerson"
     >
     </select>
  </div>
  <div>
     <button data-bind="text: 'save', click: save" />
     <button data-bind="text: 'load', click: load" />
     <button data-bind="text: 'log current person', click: log" />
  </div>
</div>
```

---

*Bonus edit: solution 1*:

```js
var currentPersonAsJson = null;

var handlerVM = function () {
  var self = this;
  self.persons = ko.observableArray([
      new PersonVM("john", 1),
      new PersonVM("paul", 2),
      new PersonVM("viki", 3),  
  ]); 
  self.currentPerson = ko.observable();     
  self.save = function () {
    currentPersonAsJson = ko.toJSON(self.currentPerson);
    console.log(currentPersonAsJson);
  }
  self.load = function () {
    self.currentPerson(currentPersonAsJson);
  }
  self.log = function () {
    console.log(ko.toJSON(self.currentPerson));
  }
}
var PersonVM = function (name, id) {
  var self = this;
  self.name = ko.observable(name);
  self.id = ko.observable(id);
}

var handler = new handlerVM();
ko.applyBindings(handler);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/SteveSanderson/knockout.mapping/master/build/output/knockout.mapping-latest.js
"></script>
<div>
  <div>
     <select data-bind="options: persons,
                        optionsText: 'name',
                        optionsCaption: 'choose a person',
                        value: currentPerson,
                        optionsValue: 'id'"
     >
     </select>
  </div>
  <div>
     <button data-bind="text: 'save', click: save" />
     <button data-bind="text: 'load', click: load" />
     <button data-bind="text: 'log current person', click: log" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please expand on solution 1, too? I tried adding `optionsValue: 'id'` to see what happens, but it didn't work.

Comment: I've added a snippet that demonstrates solution 1. `loadedPerson` now only contains an `id`, and we only have to save this `id`. If you're going with this approach, you might want to change your variable names to reflect the storing of `id`s rather than (serialized) viewmodels.

Comment: Oh, simpler than I thought. Thanks!